# fatal error: 'openssl/e_os2.h' file not found

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pysnap https://github.com/martinp/pysnap

When I run "python setup.py install", I get the following error.

```
Installed /private/var/folders/d7/qskwdy2j2615x_nr65rprs_00000gn/T/easy_install-rmJEmc/cryptography-1.3.1/.eggs/pycparser-2.14-py2.7.egg
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/_openssl.c:423:10: fatal error: 
      'openssl/e_os2.h' file not found
#include <openssl/e_os2.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have OpenSSL installed (OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015). Any idea as to what could be causing the error?

Comment: Do you have the openssl dev files installed as well? On Ubuntu it's the ``libssl-dev`` package which provides the file ``/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h``.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simple, just install the libssl-dev package. I did that and my 10 hours of hard work paid off finally. I was getting the same error and I scratched my head like for almost 10 hours. Just install the package and you'll rock.